serverless architecture in aws for a SASS application clientplane
I want to create a Sass app on aws could you check the architecture of the App. this is only the client plane of the SASS app where i will onboard users, users can buy the subscriptions, pay the bills, create, delete, update, and manage the resource i will be creating which will be in the application plane.

